# tsql - how to assign a id to temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to create a temp tables...But the problem is if multiple user will use the system there is no way to distinguish between their temporary tables. So I thought of putting an id infront of every table. This will be the unique id.
Any suggestion how to do this?

This unique id is there in my select query :

```
SELECT TABLE2.ID, TABLE2.NAME, TABLE2.ADDRESS, TABLE2.PHONE, INTO   ##TEMP_TABLE
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME
GROUP BY TABLE2.ID,  TABLE2.NAME, TABLE2.ADDRESS, TABLE2.PHONE;
```

How can I append this ID with temp table?

Comment: Do the `temp` tables need to have `##global` visibility? Also where is the unique `id` in your select query? And if it is unique can the concurrent users perhaps share one table as their rows won't clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use local temporary tables and not have to worry about it? Just prefix them with a single # mark.

Comment: If I am going to mark with single #, this table will not mix with some other user's table. Suppose if user1 creates #table1 and user 4 creates #table 1... It will not get messed up??

Comment: Nope. They are local to that user and connection. They are dropped when the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a table variable alone, and just put the `Table2.Id`s into it... That eliminates all these issues completely...

```
Declare @Ids Table (id integer primary key not null)
Insert @Ids(id)
 Select Distinct t2.ID 
    From Table1 t1 Join Table2 t2 
        On T2.Name = T1.Name
```

Then wherever yuou need the other Table2 data later on, jkust perform a joion to this temp table variable...
    -- To get stuff from table2 for only these rows ...

```
Select <table2 column data>
From Table2 t2 Join @Ids i on i.id = t2.Id
```